# How to use a controllerAs syntax within a directive template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controlleras

Here is my controller:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

Viewer.$inject = [];

function MyCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.titles = ['Hello', 'world'];
}
```

My Directive:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = [];

function flPagesArea($compile) {

    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="title in vm.titles">{{title}}</div>'
    };
    return directive;
}
```

The result is:

```
<!-- ng-repeat= title in vm.titles -->
```

Is the problem with my usage of the controller as or I'm missing something.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `controllerAs` option and the `bindToController` property. Also check the name of the function associated to directive. In your case, you never associate the flPagesArea function to directive declaration in the module.

```
    angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = ['$compile'];

function myDirective($compile) {

    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="title in vm.titles">{{title}}</div>',
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
    return directive;
}
```